# Issue Creating Laravel app

Tags: laravel-5, composer-php

I'm new to using command line tools.  I'm trying to setup laravel 5 on a mac.

Every time I try to install a new app, I'm getting the following error:

"Could not open input file: composer.phar"

I thought I had installed composer in the global bin.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you didnt move your .phar file to your path 
check this link [Laravel document](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2#install-composer)
 or [Laravel official video](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/1)
its will help you

Comment: I'm able to type in composer in the terminal window.  I did a quick test and if I type in composer validate, I get the following error: ./composer.json not found

Comment: type composer -v check you installed composer in your machin

Comment: to move the composer.phar file to bin folder try this `“sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer”`